# SQL SELECT concatenate distinct column values in comma separated value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table containing orders details. Each row of this table is such an item of an order, and each one has a column named services, that's a comma separated list of services related to that item.

| ID | order_id | services |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123 |
| 2 | 1 | 123,456 |
| 3 | 2 | 456,789 |
| 4 | 2 | 123 |
| 5 | 2 | 789,456 |

What i reached is the seguent result

| Order_Services |
| --- |
| 123,123,456 |

obtained with this query

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + services
        FROM order_detail
        WHERE order_id = 1
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')  AS Order_Services
```

I'd like to obtain a result set of concatenated services from a single order_id, but i want to remove duplicate too. The distinc in the STUFF is pretty useless cause it remove only equal columns (eg doesn't remove one of the value '123,456' and '456,123' cause aren't the same thing)

My expected result is,

for **order_id=1**

| Order_Services |
| --- |
| 123,456 |

for **order_id=2**

| Order_Services |
| --- |
| 123,456,789 |

Is there a  simple way to achieve this?

My SQL version is:

Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4035.00 (X64)   Nov 24 2008 16:17:31   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=5fa9570cf84c689320404e7648a2e71a)

or SQL code for replicate the example

```
CREATE TABLE order_detail ( ID INT  IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, order_id INT, services varchar(100));

INSERT INTO order_detail (order_id,services) VALUES (1, '123' ), (1, '123,456' ), (2, '456,789' ),(2,'123'),(2,'789,456')


SELECT 
    STUFF(
         (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + services
          FROM order_detail
          WHERE order_id = 1
          FOR XML PATH (''))
          , 1, 1, '')  AS Order_Services
```

Comment: While it's probably not what you want to hear, you'll save yourself a lot of headaches by *not* storing comma delimited values.  Databases aren't designed to work effectively with delimited values. They're optimized for rows (or sets). As a result, queries working with delimited lists are much more complicated/inefficient/error prone than they need to be, and definitely more complex than set based alternatives.

Comment: I'm tempted to say that the simplest way is to fix the schema, so that you don't have a single column "services" containing multiple concatenated service numbers. Instead have just a single service in each row. If you can't do that, then I would say get onto a version of SQL that isn't 17 years out of date, so that you get access to the `string_split` function, which can be used turn the concatenated values into separate rows, and then do a distinct on that. But I should acknowledge a personal bias against storing semi structured text and then using `for xml path` to turn it into real data.

Comment: SQL Server 2005? Erm, why are you on an almost 20-year old version?

Comment: I really do suggest getting onto a fully supported version; 2005 hasn't had any support for ~6 years (IIRC). If you *were* on a fully supported version you would have access to both `STRING_SPLIT` *and* `STRING_AGG`; trivialising this requirement. Of course, the *real* problem is your design, and that you are storing delimited data. Therefore, really you have 2 tasks: 1. Upgrade your version of SQL Server to a supported version. 2. fix your design to a normalised approach.

Comment: i know guys, is all true what you say. Is an older version of SQL server and yeah, string delimited value are not best practices, but i'm not the one who take decision about the version on the DB or the data-structure, i'm the one that have to found solution. I know the functions mentioneds, i'll simply was looking for some alternative cause i don't know if is possible to upgrade the SQL version to one not out of date. Anyway, any example also with those function will be appreciate

Comment: It's true, people posting questions here are often not in control of table structure or budget around SQL Server version, but IMHO it's a responsibility of the person doing the work and having to use extreme measures to solve problems (that should be simpler with more responsible data structure, or have been solved in newer versions or, in this case, both), to take that information back to the people who are.

Comment: In dbFiddle string-split is not recognised on 2019 or 2019 Linux. The page folowing says that it is avaliable for `SQL Server 2016 (13.x) et ultérieures ` Can anyone advise? https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Kendle [Not sure what you mean](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=f16a240c2ad96312b542606f6299288d). Are you trying to use `string-split` with a dash in the name and not `string_split` with an underscore? Are you trying to say `SELECT string_split(...)` instead of `SELECT * FROM string_split(...)`? (It's a table-valued function, so you have to treat it like a table, as the doc examples show.) Can you show a fiddle where it fails?

Comment: @AaronBertrand that's it: I was trying to do `SELECT STRING_SPLIT('Hello World',' ');`  when I do `select * 
from string_split(
'Hello World',' ')`  it works fine. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in SQL Server 2005 with a split function, e.g. from [this  post](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/09/t-sql-queries/split-strings):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_XML
(
   @List       nvarchar(max),
   @Delimiter  nvarchar(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value(N'(./text())[1]', N'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
GO
```

Then you can say:

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT d.order_id, f.Item
  FROM dbo.order_detail AS d
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_XML(d.services, ',') AS f
  GROUP BY d.order_id, f.Item
),
sub AS
(
  SELECT cte.order_id, Order_Services = STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + x.Item
      FROM cte AS x
      WHERE x.order_id = cte.order_id
      FOR XML PATH(''), 
      TYPE).value(N'./text()[1]', N'varchar(max)'), 
      1, 1, '')
  FROM cte
)
SELECT order_id, Order_Services 
  FROM sub
  GROUP BY order_id, Order_Services;
```

Output:

| order_id | Order_Services |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123,456 |
| 2 | 123,456,789 |

If you think, "wow, that's a really ugly and complicated query!" You're right. Modern versions of SQL Server support much more elegant approaches, and properly normalized data wouldn't require any such acrobatics in *any version* the first place.

The approach in SQL Server 2017+ requires no custom function or messy XML handling in either direction:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT d.order_id, s.value
    FROM dbo.order_detail AS d
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(d.services, ',') AS s
    GROUP BY d.order_id, s.value
)
SELECT order_id, STRING_AGG(value, ',')
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY order_id;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a2e2f0309efb9fb9f0ee793e0ae4e889)

Comment: it is a clear and exhausting answer. A thousand thanks. I hope to be able to upgrade to a non-obsolete version of SQL in the future so that I will be able to use a more efficient way of doing these things